# inner join not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hello everyone please help me out regarding this query which is fetching the data from four tables. Is this the right way to write the query

```
SELECT task.employee_id , task.user_id , task.service_id from task 
INNER JOIN employee  employee.name , employee.pic ON employee.pno =employee_id 
INNER JOIN user  user.name , user.pic ON user.pno = user_id 
INNER JOIN service  service.name , service.description ON service.service_id =service_id";
```

and when i fetch the data how i will display them like we do $a = $data['id'];

and its coming with error

```
Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
```

now i have updated to this

```
function viewAll()
{


$this->query = "SELECT task.employee_id , task.user_id , task.service_id, employee.name , employee.pic, user.name , user.pic, service.name , service.description
FROM task  INNER JOIN employee  ON employee.pno = task.employee_id  INNER JOIN user  ON user.pno = employee.user_id  INNER JOIN service  ON service.service_id = user.service_id;";



$rd = $this->executeQuery();
$recordsArray = array(); // create a variable to hold the informationm
while (($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rd)) ){
$recordsArray[] = $row; // add the row in to the results (data) array
}
```

and i am getting this error

```
Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
```

Comment: The use of mysqli_fetch_array doesn't match [the examples in the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)

Comment: so any suggestions from you please , what can i use other then mysqli_fetch_array in oop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not correct.

```
SELECT task.employee_id , task.user_id , task.service_id, employee.name , employee.pic, user.name , user.pic, service.name , service.description
FROM
    task 
    INNER JOIN employee  ON employee.pno = task.employee_id 
    INNER JOIN user  ON user.pno = employee.user_id 
    INNER JOIN service  ON service.service_id = user.service_id;
```

I can't tell you what it should be really but that should be *closer*. I made my best guess at your joins and column names based on the original query. All fields you want to "see" need to be in the `SELECT` clause. And when you are joining to another table you need to explain how. For instance, you are joining from `task` to `employee` so I assume that `task` has a column called `emmployee_id` (or similar) this is the field you need to join on.

Comment: please check out the question i have updated as you have said now its giving me Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,

Comment: Yes, you're getting this error (still) because the query is not valid. You should probably run it in MySQL Query Browser or the new (horrible, IMO) Workbench. Without more details regarding the structure of your tables, I can't help.

Answer (score 1):

Your query should resemble:

```
SELECT t.employee_id, 
       t.user_id, 
       t.service_id 
  FROM TASK t
  JOIN EMPLOYEE e ON e.pno = t.employee_id 
  JOIN USER u ON u.pno = t.user_id 
  JOIN SERVICE s ON s.service_id = t.service_id
```

But with your query, there's a risk of duplicate rows because of the JOINs to EMPLOYEE, USER and SERVICE having a relating record in all of them, or one of the table having more than one related child record.  Use:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       t.employee_id, 
       t.user_id, 
       t.service_id 
  FROM TASK t
  JOIN EMPLOYEE e ON e.pno = t.employee_id 
  JOIN USER u ON u.pno = t.user_id 
  JOIN SERVICE s ON s.service_id = t.service_id
```

Another way of writing the query without using DISTINCT (or GROUP BY) is:

```
SELECT t.employee_id, 
       t.user_id, 
       t.service_id 
  FROM TASK t
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM EMPLOYEE e WHERE e.pno = t.employee_id)
   AND EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM USER u WHERE u.pno = t.user_id)
   AND EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM SERVICE s WHERE s.service_id = t.service_id)
```

### when i fetch the data how i will display them like we do `$a = $data['id'];`

Use the column name, or the column alias if defined, in the PHP code to get the appropriate value:

```
$a = $data['employee_id'];
$b = $data['user_id'];
$c = $data['service_id'];
```

Comment: thanks man but its saying me Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,